# How to turn a netbook into a powerful street navigator? Inexpensive options?

Tags: gps, garmin

I want to buy a USB powered GPS module together with a mapping software. Any recommendations and various options that I have ?

Much like Garmin's MapSource software and GPS 18 USB:

> nRoute features an easy-to-use
>   interface, making it intuitive to
>   operate so you can focus on driving.
>   It offers auto-routing and
>   voice-prompting capabilities to
>   virtually any address. The GPS 18 USB
>   includes a 12 parallel channel,
>   WAAS-enabled sensor with USB
>   connection.

Comment: GPS's are so cheap, why not just buy one?

Comment: i already  carry quite a  lot of devices while travel..why not put all into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar recently - I bought a ~£20 Bluetooth GPS receiver off of eBay and used [Microsoft Mappoint](http://www.microsoft.com/mappoint/en-us/default.aspx).

It does work well, but not as portable (or cheap) as a stand alone GPS!

Answer (score 1):

i'm using a **[BU-353](http://www.usglobalsat.com/p-62-bu-353-w.aspx)** + iGuidance Maps with my 701 4G, not quite the cheapest but it works like a charm and very accurate.

of course i didn't want anything sticking out of my little roadwarrior, so it had to go inside :)

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Streets & Trips with GPS Locator](http://www.microsoft.com/streets/en-us/Products_StreetsGPS.aspx) is available from several retailers for about $50.

Answer (score 0):

I have a garmin GPS-10x that I have used with my laptop as a navigation aid, and integrated it with MSAcess to record locations.  This model used Blue Tooth which for mobile apps can be a plus.

The only thing I didn't like about it was that the mapping software used proprietary protocol, and to get it to switch to NMEA sentence mode you had to power the unit on / off.